# SQL Server : how to shrink .bak files after deleting older records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database and my intent is to delete some older records from a few tables after a certain time period, do a backup, and shrink the log file. I run a procedure every day to perform this action. However, my `.bak` continues to get bigger. Why is that?

Even after shrinking the log file and deleting older records, my `.bak` file grows more each time I back it up. How do you backup a database and have the `.bak` file be a representation of the actual size consisting in all the tables currently? Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @setDate DATE 

SET @setDate = CAST(GETDATE() - 10 AS DATE) 

DELETE recipebatches 
WHERE CAST(dates AS DATE) < @setDate 

DELETE parameterdata 
WHERE CAST(dates AS DATE) < @setDate 

BACKUP DATABASE xxxx
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\xxxx.BAK'

ALTER DATABASE xxxx
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  

-- shrink  to 1 mb.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (xxxx_Log, 1);  

ALTER DATABASE xxxx  
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

Current tables in my database - not many records but I have a 2,329,768 kB `.bak` size

[image: Current tables in my database]

Growth data for LOG and `.MDF` files:

[image]

Comment: check what growth rate is set for your Database.

Comment: I posted the image above for my growth. I believe these are the default settings. Do you see anything out of the ordinary? The <with init > worked to shrink the .bak file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SeanLange, Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Not sure If I agree on your exaggerated statement that it is a 'clear sign I am doing something horribly wrong'. You don't know the infrastructure, or isolated environment that this DB is in.  Disk Space, Longevity, Reliability, and Isolation are all top factors to consider. But thank you for bringing this controversial article to my attention. It was a good read. One practice doesn't fit all. Different circumstances for different Databases man. Peace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most likely reason for your .bak file to grow:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139776/why-is-bak-file-size-increasing-doubling-with-each-consecutive-backup-on-sql-se

The link explains how a .bak contains multiple backup sets unless you apply specific settings to the back up being performed.  This will cause your .bak to grow as you save to the same file over and over.

Also, check your compression settings as well.